# libdecnumber: decSingle vs decDouble/decQuad

Tags: c, decimal

I'm considering using the decNumber library, written by Mike Cowlishaw and hosted by GCC and ICU, for an emulator that has to support decimal float arithmetic.

In it, the usage of decDouble and decQuad seems simple enough: Just include `decDouble.h/decQuad.h` and compile and link `decDouble.c/decQuad.c` and `decContext.c`. See https://speleotrove.com/decimal/dnusers.html#example7

But decSingle is the odd one out. The corresponding header does not provide the arithmetic operation functions like the others, and just including it causes errors like `Unexpected DECPMAX value`.

How do I use decSingle?

Comment: Note: [C2X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C23_(C_standard_revision)#Other_features) offers optional decimal floating point types.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Oh yeah, thanks. Unfortunately doesn't seem to be well-supported by compilers other than GCC yet.